# Amazon MWS - error in requesting inventory report

Tags: java, api, amazon-web-services

I am fully capable of generating LookupItem requests with the Product Advertising API, including building the URL string with parameters and signing the request, but when I tried to take the model I had I modify it for the MWS RequestReport requests, I get this error message:

"Invalid Section name or version provided - onca/2011-01-01"

For some mysterious reason, it keeps adding "**onca/**" to the beginning of the date when clearly my parameters are:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Action", "RequestReport");
    params.put("Version", "2011-01-01"); //NOT "onca/2011-01-01" (version may be old)
    params.put("SellerId", MERCHANT_ID);
    params.put("SignatureVersion", "2");
    params.put("SignatureMethod", "HmacSHA256");
    params.put("ReportType", "_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_");
    //timestamp and signature params are added in the method that signs this request
    requestUrl = helper.sign(params);
```

What am I missing here? The method signs this "canonical query string" does not add it either, as evident in its success at signing LookupItem requests as I mentioned early. Does this have something to do with the way Amazon interprets the signature? But then wouldn't it say the URL/encoding don't match? Any theories? Need any more code or info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution: With AWS, requests start with ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml? and MWS with mws.amazonservices.com? (in US). When I had changed the endpoint to the MWS endpoint I failed to remove the concatenation of "/onca/xml" immediately after, located somewhere in my code. For some reason, Amazon interpreted my "Version" parameter as beginning with "/onca/xml" despite that not being the case in the URL or it being the first parameter in the signature. Oh well.

For anyone modifying an AWS signed request helper, make sure to remove any concatenation of "/onca/xml" after changing endpoint!